# Перенаправить вывод в консоль и в фаил одновременно Linux

Tags: linux, bash, потоки-данных, filestream

Необходимо чтобы лог из команды шел в консоль и в фаил одновременно, как можно такое реализовать? (bash)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418896/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-and-stdout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этого есть утилита **tee**.

```
ls | tee ls.txt | less
```

В результате выполнения будет создан файл **ls.txt** с содержимым текущей директории, а так же содержимое текущей директории будет выведено на экран.